# Collatz sequence getting last number 1 repeated

Tags: c, if-statement, while-loop, collatz

```
    // Define the recursive function.
    int collatz(int p1)
    {
        // While Loop Starting
        while (p1>1)
        {
      //when the number is even
        if(p1%2==0)
        {
            p1 = p1/2;
            printf("%d ", p1);
        //using recursion
            return collatz(p1);
        }
        // Case where number is odd.
        elseif
        {
            p1 = 3*p1+1;
           //print function
            printf("%d ", p1);
           //using recursion
            return collatz(p1);
        }
        }
     }  
    // Main body.
    int main()
    {
       // Declare the variable and initialized it.
      int p1= 4;
      //print function
     printf("User Entered value  : %d\n", p1);
       // Display the number 
        printf("%d\n", collatz(p1));
        //End
        return 0;
    }
```

Output: I am getting the Output as :
        2 ,1, 1
I should not get the last number 1 repeated.Could you please correct me where i have done mistake.Please do the needful.

Comment: 1) C and C++ are different languages. Pick one! 2) This is neither C nor C++. 3) See [ask].

Comment: I have written in C

Comment: So why added tag for a different language? Please edit your question respecting the other two issues.

Answer (score 0):

You should always enable warnings when you compile a C or C++ program. Had you done do, the compiler would have warned you that your function `collatz` could terminate without returning a value. (What happens if the argument is 1?)

That's undefined behaviour, and so is the use of the possibly-nonexistent return value in your `main` function.

So it is just a quirk of chance that it happens to print 1 in main. But whatever it printed would be wrong because you seem to expect the output to be limited to what is printed in `collatz`.

You might try playing computer and executing your function with a pencil and paper. It won't take very long. Of course, you could also use a debugger.

Comment: I am working un Linux environment.I am new to C programming.I am not aware of debugging in linux environment in vmware machine.

Comment: @chandu: yes, I suspected as much, which is why I suggested using a pencil and paper. But if you are serious about learning how to program, you will eventually have to kearn how to use a debugger.